# concat date and varchar and convert to timestamp

Tags: sql, teradata

i have column with date type, and another with varchar type, i want to concatinate this column then convert it in timestamp
i try this but doesn't work

```
CAST (adjustmentDate || adjustmenttime AS TIMESTAMP (0) FORMAT 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS' )
```

Comment: We could do with an example and desired result, if you after unix time stamp you could do something like  SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
    STR_TO_DATE('2018-01-11 01:58pm', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i%p')
);

Comment: What's the format of `adjustmenttime`?

Comment: adjustmentDate is a date 
adjustementTime is a varchar

Comment: How is the time stored in the varchar, `HHMISS` or `HH:MI:SS` or ...?

Comment: like this HHMISS

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try

```
select 
cast(adjustmentDate  as timestamp(0)) + 
( CAST (adjustmenttime  AS time(4) format 'HHMISS') - time '00:00:00' hour to second)
;
```

I works for me with some literals, so I'm hoping it can work for your table.